# How to paginate and sort results in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I need to paginate the results and sort them using sortBy(), without losing the pagination links. I also need to use a resource to return the results.

```
$sorted = Model::paginate(10)->sortBy('name');

$results = \App\Http\Resources\MyResource::collection($sorted);
```

Doing this breaks the pagination links (I get only the data part).

```
$paginated = Model::paginate(10);

$results = \App\Http\Resources\MyResource::collection($paginated);

return $results->sortBy('name');
```

This also doesn't work.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've solved the problem with this solution:

```
$sorted = Model::get()
    ->sortBy('example_function')  //appended attribute
    ->pluck('id')
    ->toArray();

$orderedIds = implode(',', $sorted);

$result = DB::table('model')
    ->orderByRaw(\DB::raw("FIELD(id, ".$orderedIds." )"))
    ->paginate(10);
```

I've appended example_function attribute to the model, to be used by sortBy. With this solution I was able to use orderBy to order by an appended attribute of the model. And also I was able to use pagination.

Answer (score 10):

Using the *getCollection()* and *setCollection()* method in the paginator class, You can update the pagination result without losing the meta data.

```
$result = Post::orderBy('another_key')->paginate();
$sortedResult = $result->getCollection()->sortBy('key_name')->values();
$result->setCollection($sortedResult);

return $result;
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you can sort the results first, and then paginate

```
$sorted = Model::orderBy('name')->paginate(10);
```

Comment: But I have a hasOne relationship with the column I want to sort. I tried doing orderBy(‘user.name’) but it doesn’t work.

Comment: public function user() {
            return $this->hasOne('App\User');
    }

Comment: can I order by user name without joining?

Comment: No, you need to join users

Comment: But then how can I use my custom Model functions from the resource if I'm using query builder to join the tables? My Model has an example_function() and in my resource I want to call $this->example_function(). I get "Call to undefined method" exception.

Comment: What the ```example_function() do```,can you show me your codes

Comment: Or you can change it to static function and put the results as parameter

Comment: I did a Model::find(id)->example_function() in the resource. It worked. Is this ok?

Comment: You can do that, but it is not the best way.However, it's only 10 records, it's find

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183977/discussion-between-josh-and-tsaikoga).

Comment: Shouldn't this be the accepted answer?