# How to order paginated data by ID or CREATED_AT separately in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, pagination, sql-order-by

I recently started learning Laravel Inertia using it with Vue JS.
I want to load list of students using a simple Eloquent relationship between **USERS** table and **STUDENTS** table.
**Relationship in Students model**

```
public function users () {
      return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
}
```

Pagination and everything else are working well. But now I want to use **ordering** feature to **order data** based on specific choice that user wants.
**Orders can be**

```
Order by First name: A-Z and Z-A
Order by Created_at: Ascending and Descending
```

When I order data by ID like this: `orderBy('id', 'DESC')` it orders ALL data. If there are 5000 rows, it orders all 5000 rows descending by IDs!
**I load and fetch data using Laravel Pagination**

```
protected function listStudents () {
   $students = User::with('students')
      ->select(
         'firstname',
         'surname',
         'email',
         'id',
      )->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(25);

   return $students;
}
```

**I pass loaded data to Inertia rederer**

```
public function index () {
   return Inertia::render('StudentsView', [
         'students' => $this->listStudents()
   ]);
}
```

My question is, how can I order bunch of paginated data separately? So, if pagination is: `paginate(25)` ONLY 25 of them should be ordered and not rest of them.
Please help me to solve this problem or if question is duplicated, please help me to find solution in duplicated thread down in the comment section. Thank you.

Comment: ***if pagination is: paginate(25) ONLY 25 of them should be ordered and not rest of them*** if you paginate for 25, no one can see the other 4975 unless they click on the second page. Is something else you need to archive?

Answer (score 0):

if you want in model then below code would be help you

```
User::orderBy('id', 'DESC')
    ->orderBy('username', 'ASC')
    ->get();
```

if you are not looking for this than as i understand you want two diffrent orderBy then you have to take dropdown for order by and on change you can change order by in your view file.

Comment: FYI: when you order by `ID`, it won't reach `username`. ***The reason is ID is always unique.***

Comment: it's just an example how we can use multiple column use for order by

Comment: Yes, I used dropdown, and i used links for each option. 
Although I can do this in front-end using Vue JS but I want to pass any changes to URL as parameters so that every time users reload the page, they don't lose their chosen order.
Before doing all of these things, I came face to face with this problem!
I'm not sure if I need to use one or more ```orderBy()```, for now, I just want to know how to do simple ordering without ordering all the paginated data.

Comment: @nageennayak In fact [I found solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53384956/how-to-paginate-and-sort-results-in-laravel).
But thanks for your time and your help.